# Stack columns row by row

Tags: r, stack

I have a dataframe which contains 2 columns, such as

```
Name                                Seq
1 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000789668 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGCGATCCATTTTCTCAGCCTATTAAATTTC
2 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814448 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTTTCAGCGGATGTTCTCTCCAGCTTTCAAC
3 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814452 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGTTTTGCTGGGCCTGCGTGATACTAGCGAT
4 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001021870 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTGTCCCGTTTCCGGACCCGTCTCTATGGTG
5 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001316145 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGATTCTCCTATGTGTGTCGTCTGCAGCCATC
6 ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001445604 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGCTGCTTGGCTTTGAGGAAGAGTGGCAGTAC
```

I wish to stack one column onto anther row by row to give:

```
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000789668
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGCGATCCATTTTCTCAGCCTATTAAATTTC
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814448 
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTTTCAGCGGATGTTCTCTCCAGCTTTCAAC
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814452 
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGTTTTGCTGGGCCTGCGTGATACTAGCGAT
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001021870 
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTGTCCCGTTTCCGGACCCGTCTCTATGGTG
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001316145 
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGATTCTCCTATGTGTGTCGTCTGCAGCCATC
ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001445604 
CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGCTGCTTGGCTTTGAGGAAGAGTGGCAGTAC
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
 data.frame(Col1=c(t(df)))
   #                                                           Col1
  #1                                ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000789668
  #2  CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGCGATCCATTTTCTCAGCCTATTAAATTTC
  #3                                ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814448
  #4  CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTTTCAGCGGATGTTCTCTCCAGCTTTCAAC
  #5                                ENSE00000789668:ENSE00000814452
  #6  CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGGTTTTGCTGGGCCTGCGTGATACTAGCGAT
  #7                                ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001021870
  #8  CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGTGTCCCGTTTCCGGACCCGTCTCTATGGTG
  #9                                ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001316145
  #10 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGATTCTCCTATGTGTGTCGTCTGCAGCCATC
  #11                               ENSE00000789668:ENSE00001445604
  #12 CTCAAAATTTGCTGCAGCAGAAATTACTGAGCTGCTTGGCTTTGAGGAAGAGTGGCAGTAC
```

Or

```
 library(reshape2)
 melt(t(df))[3]
```

Or may be this too

```
 data.frame(Col1=as.matrix(df)[c(matrix(seq(prod(dim(df))), nrow=2, byrow=2))])
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the first answer. It seems obvious now I see the how to do it!